# May a husband share his bed with multiple wives for sex, movies, sleep, etc.?

Tags: halal-haram, polygamy

Is it permissible a husband to share his bed with his two wives?
Including for sex, movies, telling stories, and sleep.

As in [Quran Chapter No 2: Verse No 223](https://quran.com/2/223): "Your wives are a place of sowing of seed for you, so come to your place of cultivation however you wish and put forth [righteousness] for yourselves. And fear Allah and know that you will meet Him. And give good tidings to the believers."

Answer (score 1):

Husband have to provide the acceptable housing and living for his wives. It is not about pleasure only. It is primarily a responsibility.

The relationship between him and his wives have to be private and no one shall see it even his other wives.

Although having visits between wives and spending good time in halal actions is good thing.

I hope I understood well and provided the requested answer.